# Limit the absolute error of the expression $((\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5})^3-2)^5$

Tags: approximation, error-propagation

> Limit the absolute error of the expression
>   $((\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5})^3-2)^5$ taking as approximation
>   $(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5})^*=0.34$.

Comment: Well, the error is surely less than $10^{78}$,

Comment: @ajotatxe Thanks for answering, how did you reach that conclusion?

Comment: Oh, it was intuition.

Answer (score 0):

[Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((sqrt%20(3)%2F5)%5E3-2)%5E5-(.34%5E3-2)%5E5) tells me it is just over $0.167$ so my limit would be $0.168$.  Any calculator can do the same.